# What's the function/purpose of the "class" Target in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, class, target

First of all i'm not sure if this is a class at all which belongs to CSS or whatsoever and i'm also not a native english speaker  but i'll try my best.
I'm new to coding and passed this challenge at Freecodecamp but did not understand why i needed to add this class. I found 2 similar questions and also looked the next challenges up , but neither the questions nor the challenges helped me understand the point of adding this class.
The name of the challenge is : Create a Class to Target with jQuery Selectors. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h3 class="text-primary text-center">jQuery Playground</h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="well">
<button class="btn btn-default target"></button>
<button class="btn btn-default target"></button>
<button class="btn btn-default target"></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="well">
<button class="btn btn-default target"></button>
<button class="btn btn-default target"></button>
<button class="btn btn-default target"></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And you got any jQuery / javascript code yet? I don't really understand the question?

Comment: google "css class meaning"

Comment: Where is the jQuery script which you have to match the classes?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/) -> [Selecting Elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

Answer (score 1):

A class belongs neither to CSS nor to JS but is part of the HTML which makes up the Document Object Model (DOM) for the website.

Suppose you have this HTML:

```
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

To target a class you use a `.` operator.

So in CSS you target a class like this:

```
.btn { background-color: red }
```

And in jQuery you would target a class like this:

```
$('.btn').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. It helped me a lot,but i don't know if i had expressed myself right. I meant to ask the purpose of writing "target" as a class like it is written in the 6th to 8th line of the code.

Comment: Ah I think I see. There are no reserved class names. That is, the class name "target" has no specific meaning. It's as arbitrary as "red", "button" or "elephant". In the code you pasted, you can target the `<button class="btn btn-default target">` with any of those classes. e.g. `$('.btn')`, `$('.btn-default')`, or `$('.target')` If you're going off the wording of the assignment (Create a Class to Target with jQuery Selectors) it doesn't mean to create a class called "target" but create a specific class that you can use in jQuery to target whatever element has that class name.

Comment: It's a little late but thanks a lot David. I figured it out at some point later and your second answer helped me to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

To David Yeiser's answer,

You can also use ECMA's method the `.querySelector` or `.querySelectorAll` method.

I know it isn't a direct answer to the question on utilizing jQuery, but I feel you can understand how class attributes and id attributes affect the DOM structure by using raw javascript rather than third-party APIs.

For example, in the structure posted:

```
document.querySelector(".well")
```

in your sandbox will return the first instance of a dom object that matches the class `well` in your document tree whereas:

```
 document.querySelectorAll(".well")
```

will bring an HTML collection of two .class nodes returned to you.

See [MDN's document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for a better understanding on querying html nodes. It will come in handy letter as the jQuery library is being used less and less in replacement for React, or Angular, or Vue for compiling and isolating your code for web building.

Comment: How is this different to jQuery? They use the same CSS selectors to find elements...

Comment: Never stated it was different. The person who asked the question said he was new to coding and I provided another approach to search for elements